# libgdx glClearColor not setting right color?

Tags: opengl, libgdx

i just new to libgdx and trying to understand the example code, the following code sets the bg color

```
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(60,181,00,0f);
```

my expected color is green,  R:60 Green:181 B:0, but the about code show me yellow color in my android app, anything  i'm doing wrong?

http://rapid-tools.net/online-color-picker/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`glClearColor` expects color values to be in `0 .. 1` range, everything outside of this range gets clamped to it. In your case numbers are getting clamped to `(1, 1, 0, 0)` which is indeed yellow.

Try setting `glClearColor(60/255.0, 181/255.0, 0.0, 0.0);` instead.

Comment: The lines should also be switched around, otherwise there will be one "wrong" frame.

Comment: @Ben: Good comment, it should be for the question though, not for the answer ;)

Comment: finally, Gdx.gl.glClearColor((float)60/255,(float)181/255,0f,0f);